# Android google mobile vision api turn on camera and torch

Tags: android, camera, torch

I am using the android google barcode vision API and I can detect my QR code perfectly.  How can I turn on the torch at the same time.  It will be required to scan a qr code at night.  Here is the working code I have so far

```
public class fragment_qrscan extends myFragment {

    SurfaceView cameraPreview;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_qrscan, container, false);

        cameraPreview = (SurfaceView)view.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

        createCameraSource();

        return view;
    }


    private void createCameraSource() {

        BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(getActivity()).build();
        final CameraSource cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getActivity(),barcodeDetector)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1600,1024)
                .build();

        cameraPreview.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                try {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
                    }

                    cameraSource.start(cameraPreview.getHolder());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });

        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {

            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {

                final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
                if (barcodes.size() >0) {
                    Log.i("myStuff",String.valueOf(barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue));
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Everything is working perfectly I just can't figure out how to turn on the torch correctly and still use the mobile vision api.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my fully working solution.  By including the CameraSource.java class [found here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java) in my project.  I am able to scan the qr code and I can toggle the camera torch on and off.

```
public class fragment_qrscan extends myFragment {

    SurfaceView cameraPreview;
    private CameraSource mCameraSource;
    private Button btnLight;
    boolean lightOn = false;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_qrscan, container, false);

        cameraPreview = (SurfaceView) view.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        btnLight = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLight);

        btnLight.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        btnLightClicked();
                    }
                }
        );

        createCameraSource(true, false);

        return view;
    }

    private void btnLightClicked() {

       if (!lightOn) {
            mCameraSource.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
           lightOn = true;

       }
        else {
           mCameraSource.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
           lightOn = false;
       }
    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void createCameraSource(boolean autoFocus, boolean useFlash) {
        Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(context).build();
        CameraSource.Builder builder = new CameraSource.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), barcodeDetector)
                .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1600, 1024)
                .setRequestedFps(15.0f);
        // make sure that auto focus is an available option
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            builder = builder.setFocusMode(
                    autoFocus ? Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE : null);
        }

        mCameraSource = builder
                .setFlashMode(useFlash ? Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH : null)
                .build();

    cameraPreview.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
                }

                mCameraSource.start(cameraPreview.getHolder());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

            mCameraSource.stop();
        }
    });

    barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
        @Override
        public void release() {

        }

        @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {

            final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
            if (barcodes.size() >0) {
                Log.i("myStuff",String.valueOf(barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue));
            }
        }
    });

    }
}
```

I am sure there is a cleaner solution but for now this code works perfectly and with auto focus set to true is is really cool how fast and easy it is to scan the qr code.  Even from 3 feet away the code is detected instantly.

Comment: Hi, did you includ CameraSource class explicitely in your project?

Comment: If you want to set focus to auto mode in this CameraSource class use e.g. `setFocusMode(FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)`, because there is no such method like `setAutoFocusEnabled(true)`.